# Not sure why optimizer is optimizing my method incorrectly

Tags: c, gcc

I'm new to C (so there's every good chance I'm doing something fundamentally wrong or bad), and working on a kattis problem, https://open.kattis.com/problems/abc.

I'm running in to fun with what appears to be the GCC optimiser and I'm trying to understand why or what I'm doing wrong.  Here's the simplest replication case I can come up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int lookup(char input){
    // This will return 2 on invalid input.  Not ideal, but we don't have to worry about invalid inputs like that
    fprintf(stderr, "Asked to compare: %s\n", &input);
    if (strcmp("A", &input) == 0){
        //fprintf(stderr, "It's an A\n");
        return 0;
    } else if (strcmp("B", &input) == 0){
        //fprintf(stderr, "It's a B\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    };
}

int main(void){
    char input[3];
    if (scanf("%3s", input) != 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong reading input\n");
        return -1;
    };
    printf("Desired Order: %s\n", input);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", lookup(input[0]),
        lookup(input[1]),
        lookup(input[2])
    );
}
```

An example input file for triggering this bug has a single line:

```
CAB
```

If I compile with without optimisations:

```
$ cc -std=gnu11 -static -lm simple.c -o simple && cat input | ./simple
Desired Order: CAB
Asked to compare: B
Asked to compare: A
Asked to compare: C
2 0 1
```

With optimisations enabled, note it's falling through to the else section:

```
$ cc -O2 -std=gnu11 -static -lm simple.c -o simple && cat input | ./simple
Desired Order: CAB
Asked to compare: B
Asked to compare: A
Asked to compare: C
2 2 2
```

Things I've noticed so far:

- If I uncomment the `fprintf` after the `strcmp("A", &input)`, the code works fine even with optimisations enabled (that's what got me wondering about optimisations breaking my code in the first place).
- If I uncomment the `fprintf` after the `strcmp("B", &input)` the code fails when optimised.
- If I comment out the "Desired Order:" `printf`, the code works fine even with optimisations.

Comment: You need an array of 4 `char`s to read 3 characters, because of the 0-terminator at the end of the string.

Comment: You can't use `strcmp` to compare a single character, there's no `NUL` terminating character. Use a regular `==` comparison.

Comment: It seems you might need to take a few steps back, and start over with (or at least refresh) the basics of characters and strings.

Comment: @mch good point.  Doesn't change behaviour here, though.

Comment: @ThomasJager that's undefined behaviour (based on compiler warnings), but it did make me revisit my use of `strcmp` there, and I should be using `strncmp`, which seems to fix the code entirely.

Comment: Why not `if ('A' == input)`? There's really no need for string comparisons, bounded or not.

Comment: @Twirrim There is no reason whatsoever to use string-based functions here. You're comparing a single character.

Comment: To quote the compiler when warnings are enabled:

`warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]`

So far as I can see, using `strncmp` is the only way to do it reliably.

Comment: Remember the difference between `"A"` and `'A'`! To reiterate myself, why not use `if ('A' == input)`? Why are you so hung up on using string comparison where it's not needed?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Gah.  You're right, forgot about the difference betwee single vs double quotes.  Most of my programming has been in languages where that isn't the case.

I wouldn't say I'm hung up on it, I was getting a compiler warning about the unspecified behaviour, which I'm aware is dangerous to rely on.  When I started reading around on string comparisons, I kept coming back to `strcmp` and `strncmp`, which both worked (well.. kinda in the first case), and did the task at hand.

Comment: Sorry for maybe being a little pushy or something. But it helped you get to that "Doh!" moment which are so important for learning :)

Answer (score 4):

```
char input[3];
```

but you wrote three characters to it. Need 1 more for null terminator.

```
char input[4];
```

And here we have

```
fprintf(stderr, "Asked to compare: %s\n", &input);
```

No. That's a character not a string so we want

```
fprintf(stderr, "Asked to compare: %c\n", input);
```

and we also have

```
strcmp("A", &input) == 0
```

but input is a `char` so we want

```
'A' == input
```

and the same for 'B'